# HTML/CSS Вывод данных

Tags: html, css, html5

**На сайте выводятся данные:**

[image: image1]

**Через цикл:**

[image: image2]

**CSS**

[image: image3]

Не очень понимаю, как сделать вывод, к примеру по 3 элемента (таблички) в ряд, ну то есть, как показано на Скрине 1.

Comment: вам нужна таблица по 3 блока в ряду?

Comment: да, как на 1 скрине

Comment: тогда вам скорее всего `display: grid` нужен для этого

Answer (score 0):

```
.card-group{ display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;}
```

Comment: не работает, всё тоже самое

Comment: @Stepan, проверьте сохранили ли вы файл css, т.к. нередко всё не работает просто из-за человеческого фактора

Answer (score 0):

Вариант на `Grid Layout`

```css
.card-group {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.card-group .card {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}

.card-group .card::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-group">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я так же могу вставить в линию больше 4 блоков, мне надо чтобы было ограничение к примеру 3, остальные переносились на следующую линию

Comment: Когда я вставил ваш код, в цикл он размешает неограниченное количество "табличек"